# go test regex type or syntax

Tags: regex, testing, go

What type or syntax of regex is used when running `go test -r <regex>` commands? I'm using `-list` to find the tests I want to run before using `-r`, like this:

```
go test -list 'Foo' *.go
```

I'm having specific difficulty with the following two test names:

```
func TestSendTrap(...
func TestSendTrapFull(...
```

This works:

```
go test -list 'TestSendTrap\b' *.go
```

So I'm presuming [PCRE syntax](https://www.debuggex.com/cheatsheet/regex/pcre) is being used, but [command go](https://golang.org/cmd/go/) doesn't detail.

Comment: A natural guess would be: "Go's own regular expression syntax!".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's Go regex, documented in [regexp/syntax](https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/).

Comment: Duh! Who knew? Thanks @hobbs.